# Достать все элементы листа с определённого индекса Java

Tags: java, spring

Есть лист, известен индекс элемента который я хочу взять, нужно взять все элементы, что лежат ниже того, который я взял и засунуть в другой лист, не могу понять как это сделать

Comment: Посмотрите на методы интерфейса List, например, subList().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<Object> someName(List<Object> anotherList, int index) {

        List<Object> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = index+1; i < anotherList.size(); i++) {
            resultList.add(anotherList.get(i));            
        }

        return resultList;
    }
```

В место Object свой тип укажи и поменя названия метода.